# Null in aggregate query

Tags: email, email-template

I have an image stored as a document. I put this image in an email template  and reference it by doing:

```
<img id="toplogo" src="{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140, FIND('.com/',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+3)}/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015G0000001f7xo&oid={!$Organization.Id}" height="20"/>
```

All good. Problem is when I build a package and installed this image in another org, it will get another Id.  I need to be able to do something like this:

```
Document document = [Select Id, Url From Document Where DeveloperName = 'MyImage'];
// can now use document.URL
```

Is it possible to execute that code in a VF Email template?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VF email template can't have a controller / controller extension. You can however embed a component (`<c:myCustomComponentTag imageName="MyLogo"/>` or something like that) and this thing could have a controller.

Alternatively inform the package installators that they'll get new Id, the can't edit your email template but they can clone it and put links to logos of their choice?

Or store the link to logo in a custom setting and again - let the client admins edit the values?

Comment: this is a good lead thanks. I have a few other questions but it makes sense to put them in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

I guess salesforce supports controller in visualforce templates. You can do the query in the controller and use the merge field to populate the image Id.

Additionally you can think of putting the image in a static resource and use {$Resource.} to import the image

Comment: static resources are not considered a good idea for email templates.