# Set parameter in email?

Tags: email, email-template

Regarding a VisualForce email template, I know it is possible to setWhatId(), setSubject() and range of other things in Messaging.SingleEmailMessage.  But I just want to set my own parameter.

Let me expand on what I mean by my own parameter.  I want to be able to use a parameter in a URL I use in img tag.

```
<img id="toplogo" src="{!$MyParameter}" height="20"/>
```

I am merging a custom object into the email.  So I could always add a parameter to this custom object and merge that way.  But is there anyway I can do it without going near my custom object?

Comment: What do you mean by wanting to set your own parameter, can you expand on your use case a bit?  Do you mean the content of the mail, for that you can use setHtmlBody and setPlainTextBody.

Comment: @Phil Hawton I have updated question.

Comment: so are you just trying to make this logo dynamic within your email template? Is there any logic to determine it?

Comment: Have you tried Custom Label or (hierarchical) Custom Setting (like I've said in http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/7352/799)?

Comment: ^ just what I was about to suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't totally understand what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to add a querystring parameter, that's pretty easy...

```
<img id="toplogo" src="http://myurl.com/image.png?myparam={!$myParameter}" height="20"/>
```

Just make sure that your parameter is URL encoded. If you are leveraging Visualforce Components in your Visualforce Email template, you could do that in your controller like so...

```
public class MyEmailController {
  public String getMyParameter() {
    EncodingUtil.urlEncode('parameter that needs encoding');
  }
}
```

And the component...

```
<apex:component controller="MyEmailController" access="global">
  <img id="toplogo" src="http://myurl.com/image.png?myparam={!$myParameter}" height="20"/>
</apex:component>
```

[Here are the docs that might help](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm)

Comment: this was a good pointer to get me going. I have another question but will take that in separate thread.