# Integrating an image into a email template using a component

Tags: email, email-template, visualforce-component, images

Thanks to a good steer in this [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7351/null-in-aggregate-query) I have managed to get an image into an email template that I can package up and put in any org.

My design:

- Stores the image as a document
- Uses a component with a custom controller
- The controller executes a query and gets the ID of the image and
- The Component then displays the image by doing:

  ```
  <apex:component controller="ImageCustomController" access="global">
      <apex:attribute name="height" description="Id for image" type="String"/>
      <apex:image value="{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140, FIND('.com/',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+3)}/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id={!ImageId}&oid={!$Organization.Id}" height="{!height}"/>
  </apex:component>
  ```

All brilliant.

However, it is difficult to place something beside my component. In my template, I do:

```
<div>
<c:ImageComponent height="20"/>
<H1>Performance Insight</H1>
</div>
```

The image component takes the width of the screen. I want it to behave just like a normal  where it is possible to put stuff beside it.

Note: In some cases I want stuff beside and in other cases I won't. So if put the stuff beside it into the actual component I will need to have some logic to know whether to display the extra stuff or not.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because it's rendered into a `<div>` (which is a block element or whatever is the official name... What I mean is that divs by default occupy 100% width).

Check this explanation for "layout" attribute of `<apex:component>`:

> The HTML layout style for the component. Possible values are "block"
>   (which wraps the component with an HTML div tag), "inline" (which
>   wraps the component with an HTML span tag), and "none" (which does not
>   wrap the component with any generated HTML tag). If not specified,
>   this value defaults to "inline".